# No way to close account on mobile

Tags: bug

I followed the instructions to delete my account, but found there was no delete button on mobile. Is it possible to delete my account without logging in on a desktop browser?

Comment: Don't your cell's browser has a 'request desktop version'. Super clunky workaround I admit... But it'll do the trick (I agree they should fix that, but if you want to delete your account now and don't have access to a PC, at least that'll get you the option)

Comment: @AniMenon, what made you do that edit? It invalidates an answer and I see no comment from the OP that would suggest your edit to be appropriate.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The OP intended to point out a bug, yes the desktop site works but that isn't the best solution.

Comment: @AniMenon That would be a [tag:feature-request] rather than a bug. The current question was answered, I would post another question for that feature request if you think the community will find it worth it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes a feature request. The mobile site should also have the option to delete account.

Comment: After 6 years you're leaving us? You'll be missed.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to delete my account without logging in on a desktop browser

**Yes**

You need to open Stack Overflow in your browser in desktop mode.

In Google Chrome on mobile, you can enable ‘Desktop site’ in the menu to display the webpage as desktop. Then you can find the option for **Delete Profile** inside of the **Edit Profile & Settings** tab.

[image: Google Chrome's mobile menu]
[image: Edit Profile & Settings page in Google Chrome on mobile]

If the "Desktop Site" option doesn't work, there is a link in the Stack Overflow footer for **full site** to switch between desktop and mobile views. Thanks to [**@psubsee2003**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368595/no-way-to-close-account-on-mobile/368597#comment594674_368597).

[image: Stack Overflow footer on mobile]

Comment: Probably depends on the browser or the site, but I've found the "Desktop site" option doesn't always work.  In the the Stack Overflow footer, there is a link to get the desktop version (assuming you are on mobile), and to get the mobile version if you are using the desktop version currently)

Comment: Not at all what I meant.  I was suggesting an addition to your answer. 
 If the "Desktop Site" option doesn't work (which has happened to me before), there is a link in the SO foot to switch between desktop and mobile views

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks please check updated answer

Comment: @Mike Please don't just haphazardly put ‘m’ on images, it then became [impossible to see the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIUdj.png) being talked about even after clicking the image.

Comment: I remember that on some platforms (iOS for example) there could only be ersatz browsers, which don't have this feature. Not sure if it's still true though (I don't own iOS-base devices) but there's a chance that it's still unreachable for some users.